# AngularJs how to set value in dynamically created html element

Tags: angularjs, dynamic-controls

I have created html elements on my page using ng-repeat, [image: Angular controls]

My problem is I don't know how to set the value on the cost column based on the dropdown on the left. Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: Can you draw it?

Comment: thanks for your attention on my question, when i choose from the first dropdown(see image), the country dropdown will enabe then when i select from the country dropdown then it will display the corresponding Cost , however on my current code it only display the the cost for first row.

Comment: You tagged the question as `angular`, which means Angular 2+, you should use the `angularjs` tag instead.